# Reactively Log Out of Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, logout, reactive

If I log out of meteor (v 1.3.2) on the server/another client, e.g. by deleting the tokens, a server-side `Meteor.call('logout')`, or calling `Meteor.logoutOtherClients()` elsewhere, my client does not seem to get notified it's been logged out.

Any `Meteor.call` simply does not run (is it queued?), and client calls to `Meteor.userId()` and `Meteor.user()` do not change, also breaking their reactive nature.  Similarly, `Accounts.onLogout` does not fire unless I'm using a client-side `Meteor.logout`.

I simply cannot find a variable that will tell me or be able to ask whether the client and server connection has been cut and the two cannot communicate anymore.  I've looked in `Accounts.connection`

I'm not even sure where to look anymore, so anything is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was returning `null` from a `publish`, and it should be either a mongo db cursor, `this.ready()` or `[]`.

This put the client in a weird state where it couldn't communicate with the server when the server logged it out, and it couldn't detect that the connection had closed reactively.